# Limit of $f(x)=|\log x|$

Tags: limits, logarithms

My textbook solved this problem:

Find $f'(1^{-})$ if

$$f(x)=|\log x|$$
for the interval $x>0$

The textbook solved it by using the method described below:
$$f'(1^{-})=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$$

Which becomes:

$$f'(1^{-})=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}} \frac{|\log x|-|\log 1|}{x-1}$$

They substituted $x=1-h$

$$f'(1^{-})=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{|\log (1-h)|-|\log 1|}{-h}$$
Now they claimed the answer to this is $-1$

I really don't understand how they arrived at that answer. Could it be a typo on their part?

Comment: I suppose there should be brackets around (1-h)?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction. Will effect it

Comment: Well log 1 = 0 and [log (1-h)/h] = log ((1-h)^(1/h)).  And lim (1-h)^(1/h) = e and log e = 1.  Not a typo.

Comment: @fleablood I thought its $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} (1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}} = e$

Comment: How does your textbook define $\log$? A common definition $$\log x = \int_1^x \frac 1t \ dt$$ makes this essentially trivial.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 natural logarithm. Exactly the solution to the integral function you wrote

Comment: Thanks guys, @GoodDeeds has explained it to me perfectly

Comment: @Obinoscopy The derivative, by the FTC, of $-\log x$ at $x=1$ is $-1$, and hence its left derivative is also $-1$. Since it is easy to see that $\log x<0$ for $0<x<1$, $|\log x| = -\log x$ in $(-\delta, 1)$ and so $|\log|$ and $-\log$ have the same left derivative at $x=1$.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. lim (1 - h)^1/h = 1/e.  But log (1-h) < 0 so |log(1-h)| = - log(1-h).  So -lim log (1-h)^1/h = -lim log 1/e = -(-1)

Comment: For $0<x<1$ we have $f(x)= |\ln x|=-\ln x$ and $f'(x)=-1/x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(1^{-})=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \frac{|\log (1-h)|-|\log 1|}{-h}$$
$$f'(1^{-})=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \frac{|\log (1-h)|-0}{-h}$$
$$f'(1^{-})=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \frac{|\log (1-h)|}{-h}$$
As $h\rightarrow0^+$, we have $1-h\lt1$, and $|\log (1-h)|=-\log (1-h)$.
$$f'(1^{-})=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \frac{-\log (1-h)}{-h}$$
$$f'(1^{-})=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \frac{\log (1-h)}{h}$$
Using L'Hospital's rule,
$$f'(1^-)=-1$$
To solve without L'Hospital's rule, using the Taylor expansion,
$$f'(1^-)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \frac{-h+\frac{h^2}{2!}-O(h^3)}{h}=-1$$

Comment: Oh, thanks! Please how can one solve this without L'hopital's rule?

Comment: @Obinoscopy How about Taylor's expansion?

Comment: Ok, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Without l'hopital

0 < 1-h < 1

So $\log(1-h) < 0$

So $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac {|\log(1-h)| - |\log 1|}{-h} =$

$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac {-\log(1-h) -\log 1}{-h} =$

$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac {\log(1-h)}{h} =$

$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\log(1-h)^{\frac 1h}  =$

$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\log 1/e  =$

$-1$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer which does not require Taylor series or the knowledge of the derivative of $\text{log}$ is to use the limit definition for $\frac{1}{e}$:

$$\frac{1}{e} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1- \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \lim_{m\rightarrow 0} \left( 1- m \right)^{1/m} $$

So that:

$$ -\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\left| \text{log}(1-h) \right|}{h}=-\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \left| \text{log}(1-h)^{1/h} \right| = - \left| \text{log} \left( \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} (1-h)^{(1/h)} \right) \right| $$

$$ = -\left| \text{log} \left(1/e \right) \right| = - \left| -1 \right|=-1 $$